# java code to instantiate another java file

Tags: java, groovy

I want to write a program to dynamically invoke a method inside another Java class (uncompiled) whose file name with location is given. For this I've used the following code but it wasn't working.

```
//folder location of my java file to be loaded
String url = "C:/Temp/testcases/test.java"; 
//name of the java file to be loaded
String classname = "test.java"; 
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL(url+str));
Class.forName(str).newInstance();
```

The above instance is unable to invoke the method inside the java file that I want to load dynamically. What is the error in it?

Comment: You may want to compile that java file...

Comment: Some things are not possible without reflection, but many things that use reflection are simply bad design.  Why are you using dynamic class loading rather than adding the compiled class file to the run-time class-path of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your answer. The error in the above code is with the new URL(C://...). Had I mentioned the package name wrt path correctly, it should have worked. Anyways I was dealing with groovy files so I found this code more efficient than the normal class.forname that I've mentioned above.

```
def sourceString = (new File(C:/xyz.groovy)).getText()
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(sourceString);
template =  groovyClass.newInstance()
```

Answer (score 3):

The class loader is only able to load compiled classes. It's not able to open Java source files, compile them on the fly, and load their class.

Moreover, a class name is not the same as a file name.

Comment: Well can you think of any other method to load the java source file instead of compiling it on the fly ?

If compiling it is on the fly is the only way, how do we do it within the code?  In my case the classname and the file name are same.

Comment: There are some examples of the Java 6 compiler API here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/Java-Compiler-tools.htm